# why is the function not giving the highest value of score column for each group of cluster column the top rank?

Tags: r, rank, tapply

I have a `dataframe` dt like below

```
            kmeans  sd1         sd2         score       gene
B4GALNT1    1       1.138399    0.9302788   0.59238585  B4GALNT1
GATA2       1       1.31817     0.9869005   0.70160114  GATA2
KBTBD8      1       0.2799195   0.25295     2.56658313  KBTBD8
LYPD6       1       0.5885738   0.5277333   1.1797581   LYPD6
MSX1        1       0.2846179   0.5276349   1.31276755  MSX1
NAP1L2      1       0.5778767   0.5252137   1.29646305  NAP1L2
PLA2G4C     1       1.545634    0.3505845   1.02694161  PLA2G4C
SLC6A15     1       3.6862153   1.7656347   0.31940624  SLC6A15
SNORA9      1       49.5847239  23.059789   0.01679016  SNORA9
STX1A       1       4.753248    2.3649298   0.17053974  STX1A
TRNP1       1       54.1230886  19.7797807  0.01907904  TRNP1
AKAP6       2       2.7115279   0.1346139   1.12646609  AKAP6
C1QL3       2       3.1646016   0.3646613   0.78840387  C1QL3
CAMK2N1     2       48.4399203  3.628805    0.05655038  CAMK2N1
CDK5R1      2       3.3858407   0.2249831   0.6292364   CDK5R1
CLSTN2      2       1.0131585   0.162797    1.96050927  CLSTN2
CNTN1       2       3.7191809   0.253088    0.83650197  CNTN1
DGKG        2       0.4607949   0.2333855   1.70445926  DGKG
DPF1        2       1.6369965   0.1873143   1.07265653  DPF1
FAM131A     2       8.7092498   1.763698    0.11250896  FAM131A
```

I intend to generate the below table with the below order by ranking the rows with group from `kmeans` column and extracting the rank inside of each `kmeans` group based on column `score`. So it should look like below

Desired output:

```
            kmeans  sd1         sd2         score       gene        rank
B4GALNT1    1       1.138399    0.9302788   0.59238585  B4GALNT1    7
GATA2       1       1.31817     0.9869005   0.70160114  GATA2       6
KBTBD8      1       0.2799195   0.25295     2.56658313  KBTBD8      1
LYPD6       1       0.5885738   0.5277333   1.1797581   LYPD6       4
MSX1        1       0.2846179   0.5276349   1.31276755  MSX1        2
NAP1L2      1       0.5778767   0.5252137   1.29646305  NAP1L2      3
PLA2G4C     1       1.545634    0.3505845   1.02694161  PLA2G4C     5
SLC6A15     1       3.6862153   1.7656347   0.31940624  SLC6A15     8 
SNORA9      1       49.5847239  23.059789   0.01679016  SNORA9      11
STX1A       1       4.753248    2.3649298   0.17053974  STX1A       9
TRNP1       1       54.1230886  19.7797807  0.01907904  TRNP1       10
AKAP6       2       2.7115279   0.1346139   1.12646609  AKAP6       3
C1QL3       2       3.1646016   0.3646613   0.78840387  C1QL3       6
CAMK2N1     2       48.4399203  3.628805    0.05655038  CAMK2N1     9
CDK5R1      2       3.3858407   0.2249831   0.6292364   CDK5R1      7
CLSTN2      2       1.0131585   0.162797    1.96050927  CLSTN2      1
CNTN1       2       3.7191809   0.253088    0.83650197  CNTN1       5
DGKG        2       0.4607949   0.2333855   1.70445926  DGKG        2
DPF1        2       1.6369965   0.1873143   1.07265653  DPF1        4
FAM131A     2       8.7092498   1.763698    0.11250896  FAM131A     8
```

But this is not what I am getting when I am appyling the below code

```
dt$rank <- unlist(with(dt, tapply(score, kmeans, function(x) rank(x,ties.method= "first"))))
```

Ideally inside of each `kemans` column the rows having the higest value for `score` should be given rank 1 but that is not what I see with the above command. Where am I going wrong?
Or is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: I think some rank are not correct in your expected output.  For ex. the rank '9' and '8' for kmeans 2

Comment: can you highlight where? The score column is fine, the rank which I am mentioning might not be correct but the idea is to rank inside of each kemeans group by score column where rank 1 should be for the highest score for that kemans column

Comment: I meant the `rank` for `CAMK2N1     8` and `FAM131A     9`.  Should it be the other way

Comment: yes sorry, will reorder it.

Comment: Similarly the ranking for 5 and 6.

Comment: thanks @akrun very sorry for the messed up desired result. But I guess am able to convey my message. I edited. I ranked them on my own just to show what my intentions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `ave` instead of `tapply`.  The advantage of `ave` is that it will keep the original order of the rows while getting the output

```
dt$rank <- with(dt, ave(-score, kmeans, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")))
dt$rank
#[1]  7  6  1  4  2  3  5  8 11  9 10  3  6  9  7  1  5  2  4  8
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
     group_by(kmeans) %>%
     mutate(rank = dense_rank(-score))
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(kmeans = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), sd1 = c(1.138399, 
1.31817, 0.2799195, 0.5885738, 0.2846179, 0.5778767, 1.545634, 
3.6862153, 49.5847239, 4.753248, 54.1230886, 2.7115279, 3.1646016, 
48.4399203, 3.3858407, 1.0131585, 3.7191809, 0.4607949, 1.6369965, 
8.7092498), sd2 = c(0.9302788, 0.9869005, 0.25295, 0.5277333, 
0.5276349, 0.5252137, 0.3505845, 1.7656347, 23.059789, 2.3649298, 
19.7797807, 0.1346139, 0.3646613, 3.628805, 0.2249831, 0.162797, 
0.253088, 0.2333855, 0.1873143, 1.763698), score = c(0.59238585, 
0.70160114, 2.56658313, 1.1797581, 1.31276755, 1.29646305, 1.02694161, 
0.31940624, 0.01679016, 0.17053974, 0.01907904, 1.12646609, 0.78840387, 
0.05655038, 0.6292364, 1.96050927, 0.83650197, 1.70445926, 1.07265653, 
0.11250896), gene = c("B4GALNT1", "GATA2", "KBTBD8", "LYPD6", 
"MSX1", "NAP1L2", "PLA2G4C", "SLC6A15", "SNORA9", "STX1A", "TRNP1", 
"AKAP6", "C1QL3", "CAMK2N1", "CDK5R1", "CLSTN2", "CNTN1", "DGKG", 
"DPF1", "FAM131A")), .Names = c("kmeans", "sd1", "sd2", "score", 
"gene"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("B4GALNT1", "GATA2", 
"KBTBD8", "LYPD6", "MSX1", "NAP1L2", "PLA2G4C", "SLC6A15", "SNORA9", 
"STX1A", "TRNP1", "AKAP6", "C1QL3", "CAMK2N1", "CDK5R1", "CLSTN2", 
"CNTN1", "DGKG", "DPF1", "FAM131A"))
```

Comment: The ave does not rank in the desired order am seeking. Ideally it should produce ranking for kmeans=1 based on the score column with highest score as rank 1 for the kmeans=1 and similar for other kemans=2,3,... But the ave one does not so.

Comment: @vchris_ngs  I am not sure why it is different as I get the expected output

Comment: strangely , even I cannot understand why it should not. Actually my dataframe is much bigger with more columns and also has rownames which is exactly the column `gene`, but that should not break the arrangement. Right? I can subset the columns and try to see. Let me check

Comment: @vchris_ngs  I updated with the data I used.  Please check the `str(yourdata)`

Comment: it is fine. Seems like some problem with my data. Your data is perfectly fine. I have to understand why it is failing in my case. It should work. Thanks

Comment: strangely, I subsetted the columns for the exact columns I put here and I have to be precise 94 observations and it does not give a proper ranking. Really cant get why. This is something very strange for me now.

Comment: @vchris_ngs  Are you sure that the `score` column is `numeric` class

Comment: Yes, just checked. It is indeed. `'data.frame': 94 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ obj.down.4$kmeans$cluster: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sd1                      : num  1.138 1.318 0.28 0.589 0.285 ...
 $ sd2                      : num  0.93 0.987 0.253 0.528 0.528 ...
 $ score                    : num  0.592 0.702 2.567 1.18 1.313 ...
 $ gene                     : chr  "B4GALNT1" "GATA2" "KBTBD8" "LYPD6" ...`

Comment: @vchris_ngs  It is a bit strange though.  I am using `R 3.4.0`

Comment: mine is 3.3.1, not sure what is happening. I am digging but thanks for the input. In idea case your code is correct. I will accept it.

Comment: @vchris_ngs  `3.3.1` is not that old.  Let me test it on an older version of R

Comment: @vchris_ngs  I tested on R 3.1.3 and I get the same result `with(dt, ave(-score, kmeans, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")))
 #[1]  7  6  1  4  2  3  5  8 11  9 10  3  6  9  7  1  5  2  4  8`

Comment: I renamed by col names . in my actual `df `I had a `colnames` `obj.down.4$kmeans$cluster` which is the k`meamns` col on which the groupby should be done. I changed it to `kmeans` and performed the operations and it works perfectly. Not sure if that was breaking it. Problably that was the problem but not sure.